# Making a Music Queue Unique to Each Server (Python Discord Music Bot)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm fairly new to Discord bot development and programming in general, and I have been working on a music bot (I know, very original) to get my feet in the door. I've got the bot working perfectly as I want to, but for one server. When the bot is being used by multiple servers, the song queue and variables that determine if a song is being played, paused, etc., are shared among each server, which is obviously an issue.

These are my music-related variables (I append to the music_queue whenever a user plays a new song):

```
class music_cog(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

    self.found_title = ""
    self.found_duration = ""
    self.current_title = ""
    self.current_duration = ""
    self.current_mention = ""
    self.is_playing = False
    self.is_paused = False
    self.music_queue = []
```

I append to the music_queue when the user requests a new song:

```
self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
```

And I determine which song to play by reading the first entry in the music_queue and popping it:

```
m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

self.music_queue.pop(0)

self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
```

I add the 'music_cog' to my Discord bot in the main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from help import help_cog
from music import music_cog

activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = "!help")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", activity = activity)

bot.remove_command('help')

bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
```

The question is, how do I make the music-related variables unique to each Discord server (guild) that the bot is running on? I have tried multiple possible solutions from the internet but can't get anything working.

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to use databases or json files. Sometimes, these data structures can get very complicated and that utilizes too much resources as well.

Comment: You can use a dictionary (or database as previously mentioned, which is a lot better especially if your bot is in many guilds) of guild id to their data and save them using pickle or json to a file.